# android emulator just showing the string "android" in eclipse (ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm running a project with an emulator. It is coming up an showing a message "android". No app is being run.
I'm using Android SDK with Eclipse Indigo (classic) in Ubuntu 11.10
There is no error in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like your emulator is still booting. How long have you waited?